# Partial Validation - ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am doing both client and server side validation and for one particular View I need to validate a field that isn't posted in the other views. How can I do this if I'm using the same model for both?

Comment: Can you show some code for the model?

Comment: You can do specific client-side validation on the new view, but on the server side I think you're going to need a bit of view-specific code to perform the validation on the other field, if you're using the same ViewModel.  I don't know of anything "out of the box" that fulfills the concept of "view-specific validation."

Comment: Thanks Robert.  Would that view specific validation basically be implemented by directly generating an error message for the View versus use of validation methods?

Answer (score 1):

If one view models isn't suitable for both views then you should have two view models.

To stay DRY (Don't repeat yourself) you can inherit one view model from the other and add the additional property.

Answer (score 0):

**FluentValidation** is perfect for this scenario.  You can write two different validator classes and invoke them depending on your context.  Check out their CodePlex site below:

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/